# Simulating high latency in load test

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have a Visual Studio web performance test that I am planning on running with a variety of network mixes to simulate different network conditions. However when I report this I would like to know context of this (actual bandwidth, latency in ms, etc.). The best information I've found is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997557.aspx

Specifically what I would like to know is: What is the intra-continental connection's properties?

Is there a better reference on this?

Comment: Check the files in folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Templates\LoadTest\Networks". They specify the network characteristics and may provide what you need. Adjust the "12.0" for your version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by AdrianHHH, you can find *.network file for each of available network profile at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio XXX\Common7\IDE\Templates\LoadTest\Networks` e.g.IntracontinentalWAN.network. This file contains all settings for a network file like Latency, Packet Loss, Queue Management etc.

A good description of all properties are available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rubel/archive/2011/06/05/load-test-how-to-create-a-custom-network-profile-for-network-emulation.aspx). There is not problem to edit an existing profile and to create a new one just for your specific

So, the intra-continental connection's properties are

```
<NetworkEmulationProfile name="Intra-continental WAN 1.5 Mbps" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
<Emulation>
  <VirtualChannel name="ICWAN-Channel2">
    <FilterList />
    <VirtualLink instances="1" name="link1">
      <LinkRule dir="upstream">
        <Bandwidth>
          <Speed unit="kbps">1500</Speed>
          <QueueManagement>
            <NormalQueue>
              <Size>100</Size>
              <QueueMode>packet</QueueMode>
              <DropType>DropTail</DropType>
            </NormalQueue>
          </QueueManagement>
        </Bandwidth>
        <Latency>
          <Fixed>
            <Time unit="msec">50</Time>
          </Fixed>
        </Latency>
      </LinkRule>
      <LinkRule dir="downstream">
        <Bandwidth>
          <Speed unit="kbps">1500</Speed>
          <QueueManagement>
            <NormalQueue>
              <Size>100</Size>
              <QueueMode>packet</QueueMode>
              <DropType>DropTail</DropType>
            </NormalQueue>
          </QueueManagement>
        </Bandwidth>
        <Latency>
          <Fixed>
            <Time unit="msec">50</Time>
          </Fixed>
        </Latency>
      </LinkRule>
    </VirtualLink>
  </VirtualChannel>
</Emulation>
</NetworkEmulationProfile>
```

Comment: Well done for finding the blog post describing the properties.